# Finding the element count of an stl deque in windbg

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, windbg, deque

How can I find the element count of an STL deque container in windbg?

It appears that the !stl extension doesn't support deques. I've tried looking into the internals of the data structure, but haven't found an obvious member variable for element count.

I have a memory dump of a non-reproducible issue, so logging isn't an option for me.

Comment: That would certainly depend on the innards of the STL implementation you are using.

Comment: @sbi - Good point. I'm using the Microsoft Standard C++ Library for VS2008

Comment: `std::deque` should have a data member named `_Mysize`.

Comment: @James - You're right. I wrote and debugged a small test program and _Mysize does appear to hold the element count. I saw _Mysize before, but it had an insanely large number (0x70c54800) in my dump; so I didn't think it could possibly be the element count. If you put this in an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @pepsi: The insane number hints at a problem. Either there isn't a real `std::deque` anymore where the code assumes it to be (dangling pointer/reference), or it's been overridden by a rogue algorithm.

Comment: @sbi - Thanks, I realized that after trying out the test program. I went back and looked at the dump, and it looks like the deque object isn't valid. I'm pretty sure it's just windbg messing with the pointers on my stack because of compiler optimization..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent Visual C++ Standard C++ Library implementations--at least Visual C++ 2008 and Visual C++ 2010--`std::deque` has a `_Mysize` data member that holds the number of elements in the container.